# Is better to think of the '=' operator as morphing?

Tags: c++

This is probably a trivial question.

I have minimal background in c++ and if I remember correctly I have been told to think of this operator this way:

```
int x = 1,y = 2;
x = y; //Put whatever is in y into x;
```

But after reading about Lvalues and Rvalues, I think its more suitable to think of it this way: morph (change) whatever is in x into whatever is in y. 
The reason I think this is because the object that is referenced by x semantically is still the same object right?

Comment: The assignment operator `=` Copies what in its `rValue` into its `lValue` this latter is a `non-constant` operand. It doesn't do anything with "Changing the object".

Comment: @Raindrop7 There are no rvalues in the code shown. At least not in the code involving assignment.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes there are, due to lvalue-to-rvalue conversion :-)

Comment: What's the difference?! "Assigning to an object" and "morphing an object to be like another object" sound pretty similar to me.

Comment: @juanchopanza: What do we call x and y in `x = y`?

Comment: @Raindrop7 I call them lvalues, although technically there is an lvalue to rvalue conversion involved so that the lvalue expression `y` can be used in the assignment to `x`.

Comment: "The value of the object is replaced, but the object remains the same", so essentially means the same thing as morphing the object I guess. But notice I said semantically, so all this is implementation defined and depends on the language I guess. For example, In python, objects are actually moved around and the type is assigned to the object instead of the variable.

Comment: `x` still refers to the same memory location as before the assignment if that's what you're asking

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it makes a difference for data type `int` whether you view the replacement of it's value as "put whatever is in x into y" or as "morphing". Anyway, this [online c++ standard draft concerning assignment operator](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.ass#2) describes the process as follows:

> 5.17 (2) In simple assignment (=), the value of the expression replaces that of the object referred to by the left operand.

Not sure if this answers your question, but taking this formulation one could say that "the value of the object is replaced, but the object remains the same".

Comment: It is actually very important that you keep these semantics when overloading operators.  There is nothing worse than operators behaving “unexpectedly”.